# Alternative to storing Code in a database for a game

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sails.js

### Yes, this does sound like a bad idea. But I can't think of a better way...

I am writing a card game. Players play cards. Each card has an action that changes based on the mana spent to play it. I am trying to use Sails (node.js) or Rails to do this. Example Cards:

Card 1

> Does 2*Mana damage to a target

Card 2

> Heals 3*Mana damage to a target

The issue I run into is with random cards that may summon creatures etc.

> Summons a monster with 2*Mana HP.

**How can I have a database for my `Card` model when each instance of the model has a different action?**

My first (terrible) thought: Have an "action" column that stores the method of the model in the DB (sails.js):

```
// Card1: 
console.log(card.method);
// prints: 
"function(m, target){ target.hp= target.hp - m*2}"

// Card2: 
console.log(card.method);
// prints: 
"function(m, target){ target.hp= target.hp + m*3}"
```

This seems like a terrible idea, even though my DB would hopefully not be available externally. What is a better way?

Comment: My only other thought would be to possibly store a function name in the DB? use a map to look that up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a case for [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) (STI). You can have a **single `cards` table** that will have a `type` (String) column besides the `id` and that column will be automatically filled with the class name of the particular instance.

Then, you would create a **hierarchy of `Card` classes**, each with their own specific behavior, but still sharing common code and still being stored in the single table. This is in essence how STI works.

For example (supposing that Cards have the `type` and also e.g. a `strength` attribute):

```
class Card < ActiveRecord::Base
  # some common methods for all cards
end

class HarmingCard < Card
  def do_action
    puts "harm #{strengh} x mana damage to target"
  end
end

class HealingCard < Card
  def do_action
    puts "heal #{strengh} x mana damage"
  end
end

class SummoningCard < Card
  def do_action
    puts "summon a monster with #{strengh} x mana"
  end
end
```

Comment: This may work... I do have 22 cards. Most of them could fall into those classes... and the ones that don't could just be their own class.

Comment: If you had lots of types with only very minor differences in functionality, another approach would be to use a single `Card` class and use a `kind` attribute to differ between the card types. And in the `do_action` method you would use some `case kind`  style to call to the specific behavior. On the other hand, I tend to prefer the solution proposed in the answer, as you generally hardly know in advance how will the differences between the individual card types grow in the future.

Comment: Gotcha. That helps. I it may depend... I will probably do this and add a fourth class of `SpecialCard` or something that does the `case` statement.